# how to find limit of Arithmetic progression equation

Tags: calculus, limits, arithmetic-progressions

i try to find limit of equation, where d!=0,
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{S_n}{a^2_n}
$$
i use some formulas to find limit, but it's give me nothing, irreducible fraction:
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{S_n}{a^2_n} =  \frac{\frac{a_1 + a_1 + (n-1)d}{2} * n}{(a_1 + (n-1)d)^2} = \frac{\frac{2a_1n+n^2d-dn}{2}}{(a_1+nd-d)^2} = a_1^2+(nd)^2-d^2 + 2(a_1nd-n(d^2) -a_1d)=a^2_1 + (nd)^2 - d^2+2a_1nd -2n*d^2 -2a_1d =\frac{2a_1n+n^2d-dn}{ 2a^2_1+2(n*d)^2-2d^2-4a_1nd-4n*d^2-4a_1d}
$$

where i did mistake and how to find limit, there are should be some easy way, no?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean $n\rightarrow\infty$ instead of $x\rightarrow\infty$, because the variable does not appear in the limit and everything turns into simple operations with fractions. In solution I'm gonna finding limit if $n\rightarrow\infty$ and $d\neq0$.

$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{S_n}{a_n} &= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\frac{(a_1 + a_n) n}{2}}{a_n^2} \\
&= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{(a_1 + a_n) n}{2a_n^2} \\
&= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{(2a_1 + d(n-1))n}{2(a_1+d(n-1))^2} \\
&= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{(2a_1 + d(n-1))n}{2(a_1^2+2 a_1 d(n-1) + d^2(n-1)^2)} \\
&= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{(2a_1 + d(n-1))n}{2(a_1^2+2 a_1 d(n-1) + d^2(n-1)^2)} \frac{n^2}{n^2} \\
&= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\frac{2a_1}{n} + d(1-\frac{1}{n})}{2\left(\frac{a_1^2}{n^2}+2 a_1 d(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}) + d^2\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^2\right)} \\
&= \frac{d(1-0)}{2(0 + 0 + d^2(1-0))} = \frac{d}{2d^2} = \frac{1}{2d}
\end{align*}
$$

To be honest, I think it's an obvious answer to this question.

Comment: It's $a_n^2$ in the denominator, not $a_n$.

Comment: Thanks, i gonna edit

Comment: Fixed my fault where i miss square

Comment: thanks, i just trying self-taught calculus, so for me even easy things can be hard:)

Comment: How is it obvious?